Ctypes method to specify the location of popup window (Python)
I am using ctypes to make popups in python and I am trying to make a program which creates 50 popups in random positions of the screen, however I am done with making the 50 popups appear simultaneously using threading but It all is appearing in the centre which looks kind of like a single popup. Help me please.
Code I am using
import ctypes 
import threading
# An included library with Python install. 
def Mbox(title, text, style): 
    return ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, style) 
if __name__ =="__main__":
    for i in range(20):
        t =threading.Thread(target=Mbox, args=("title","message",1,))
        t.start()
    
    print("Done!")

I am trying to make the popups appear at random locations so if you could also help me out on that one, it would be so much helpful :)

The way you're calling MessageBox (although it works) is incorrect (it's given as an example in [Python.Docs]: ctypes - Function prototypes).
Check [SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer) for a common pitfall when working with CTypes (calling functions).
I remembered a while ago I encountered this very same issue which appeared to have a solution (that I didn't test at the time): [SO]: How do I hook a ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW by using ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowsHookExW? (@CristiFati's answer), so I went ahead and try implementing it, but so far, I have no luck the Python process crashes when entering the callback.
Then, I went forward and tried directly from C, and things seemed to work, so I created a Python wrapper (PyCFUtils) that I uploaded to [PyPI]: pycfutils (python -m pip install pycfutils). Package also contains other stuff, I incorporated this functionality inside (answer history can testify that I had other alternatives before reaching this state).
Here's how to use it.
code00.py:
import random
import sys
import threading

from pycfutils import gui
from pycfutils.gui import constants


def mbox(title, text, style):
    x = random.randint(0, 1500)
    y = random.randint(0, 900)
    print(f"MessageBox at: {x}, {y}")
    return gui.message_box(title, text, x=x, y=y, style=style)


def main(*argv):
    for i in range(3):
        t = threading.Thread(target=mbox, args=("Title", "Message", 1))
        t.start()
    gui.message_box("Title", "Final message", style=constants.MB_CANCELTRYCONTINUE | constants.MB_ICONSTOP | constants.MB_DEFBUTTON3)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(
        "Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(
            " ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
            64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32,
            sys.platform,
        )
    )
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)

Output:

